# Does PM2 have a command to start a new process or restart existing one if the process's name is the same?

Tags: next.js, pm2, codeship

I'm using codeship to autodeploy my nextjs app from github. My deployment script is as follows

```
ssh user@SERVER_IP 'cd projectfolder/; git checkout master; git pull; npm run build; pm2 delete app; pm2 start npm --name "app" -- start;'
```

If I don't delete the process first the app will be duplicated with the next push.

This config works fine, but I'm kinda not sure about that deleting thing, since I found that there is a cleaner command like startOrRestart that will start a new one or restart existing process with the same name. I couldn't get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

It should be very easy with `pm2 restart appName`, in your case you only need to run

```sh
npm restart app
```

every time you need to restart your application, given that you initially start your application with

```sh
pm2 start npm --name app -- start
```

Comment: This command won't work if I don't have the app running. I was looking for a solution with the logic "start the app if there is no app with the same name; if there is is then restart".

Comment: After you start your app with `pm2 start npm --name app -- start`, run `pm2 save`, from that on your can keep using `npm restart app`

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having issue, feel free to contact CodeShip Support!

Best,
-M